# How do I get rid of scrolling?

Tags: html, scroll

I did not understand how to get rid of a vertical scrollbar on my page. This is my page html. Navbar at the top of the page is bootstrap navbar fixed top:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Mindblow</title>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
  </nav>

  <div id="main-wrap">
  <div id="responsive-admin-menu">
    ssss

  </div>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
   Content Here
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
@import url("bootstrap.css");

html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #4D5360;
  margin:0;
}

body > .row {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;

}

/*Page Structure*/

#main-wrap{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
  bottom:52px; 
  top:0;}

#responsive-admin-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height:auto !important;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  left:0px;
  top:67px;
  bottom:0px;
 z-index:20;
}

#content-wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 52px;
padding:15px;
margin:15px 15px 0 0;
left: 190px;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100% !important;
right: 0px;
background:#f1f1f1;
box-shadow:0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}
```

I think the problem is with the wrappers margin, but I need them.

How do I get rid of the vertical scrolling?

Comment: Just for your information, self closing tags are not valid in HTML5 spec, so you probably want to remove them from your `<meta>` and `<link>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for info Mark. But it is more important for me now to find solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was mainly caused by the height / min-height 100% on content-wrapper since that isn't able to occupy 100% height (since you're also setting a top).

I was able to create a jsFiddle that recreated the problem, then fixed it by replacing the height 100% with a bottom value instead, e.g.

```
#content-wrapper {
    bottom: 52px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**[See my jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/mz9h8/1/)**

Comment: O my god! You genius!

Comment: But that caused another problem - content inside #content-wrapper overflow it. :(

Comment: Adding overflow:auto fixes this by making the content-wrapper div scrollable if necessary (see updated answer and fiddle). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't need any scrolls - #content-wrapper heigh must be autoresizable depending on content height in it, without any bars.

Comment: So then just take the bottom off that div? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grantgibson/mz9h8/2/

Comment: Dear Grant, it is a variant! But page is now looking inaccurate. #content-wrapper is too short by height now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid the requirements are no longer clear to me. It's not clear *exactly* what you want to happen in different scenarios of screen size and content length which may or may not require scrolling.  Your original question was about getting rid of the vertical scroll bar, but that's not possible if you have more content than will fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/mz9h8/7/)

```
#content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 52px;
    padding:15px;
    margin:15px 15px 0 0;
    left: 190px;
    height: auto !important;
    bottom: 52px;
    right: 0px;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    box-shadow:0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    overflow: auto;
    width: 64%;
}



Hope this helps to get rid of scroll bar :)
```